# Indenting everything in Sublime text

Tags: python, sublimetext3, indentation, text-indent

How can I quickly indent everything in a certain place using sublime text 3.

For example:

```
print ('hi')
print(o)
a = 1
if a > 2:
    return False
```

Say I wanted to put that code into a def function quickly without individually indenting everything. How would I do this so that my code looks like this.

```
def a(o):
    print('hi')
    print(o)
    a = 1
    if a > 2:
        return False
```

Comment: [This](https://superuser.com/questions/536768/how-to-shift-a-block-of-text-to-the-right-left-in-sublime-text-2) super user question has your answer.  Granted, that's SublimeText 2, but I'd take odds that it'll still work in 3.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the text and press tab.

([Demonstration](https://gfycat.com/AffectionateAnxiousAnnashummingbird))

Answer (score 0):

You select the text and press *tab* to indent it.

And you can press *shift+tab* to remove the indents.

Comment: For IDLE, you should use CTL+ ] / CTL+ [ (Though I would suggest a different editor, eg VSCode, PyCharm Community, Sublime, Spyder, Ninja, Atom,  etc)

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the code and write the def meaning:

```
def a(o):
```

Then paste the code inside the def then highlight the code inside the def and do tab